# center button programmatically and dynamic layout

Tags: android, button, layout, center

I try to set the button in the center of layout but not work, I need to center the item not the text. The code is:

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
sv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E7E7E7"));
linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E7E7E7"));
sv.addView(linearLayout);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonHeader.length(); i++) { setting textview and edittext to the layout}

Button datos_OK = new Button(DataObjectActivity.this);
    datos_OK.setText("Aceptar");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams testLP = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    testLP.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

    datos_OK.setLayoutParams(testLP);
    datos_OK.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_drawable_init);
    datos_OK.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    linearLayout.addView(datos_OK);
```

That code not works on my phone and i don't know why. Another question, how can I set colour to my code? Thanx a lot.

Comment: how could you set `RelativeLayout` parameters in `LinearLayout`??

Answer (score 1):

replace your code with this

```
    // find main layout from xml
    linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llmain);
    linearLayout1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E7E7E7"));

    // Add Scrollview and linearlayout
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    sv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    sv.addView(linearLayout);
    linearLayout1.addView(sv);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // setting textview and edittext to the layout
    }

    // Genrate button dynamically
    Button datos_OK = new Button(this);
    datos_OK.setText("Aceptar");
    datos_OK.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams testLP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    testLP.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
    datos_OK.setLayoutParams(testLP);
    linearLayout.addView(datos_OK);
```

and Your xml should look like below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/llmain"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@android:color/black"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

then you will get output like below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it wrong

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
```

you should use ids which are defined in the XML:

```
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myScrollView);
linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
```

and in the XML

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/myScrollView"
    ..... >
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
    .....>
```

Comment: If i do like this i think i cant add object dinamically, or yes?

Comment: yes you can add the `View`s to the `LinearLayout` during runtime but make sure you dont use `RelativeLayout` properties and also `ScrollView` can have only one child. in this case `linearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Hi Kindly check with the below code..

```
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    sv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#394343"));
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E7E7E7"));
    sv.addView(linearLayout);

    Button datos_OK = new Button(this);
    datos_OK.setText("Aceptar");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams testLP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    testLP.setLayoutDirection(Gravity.CENTER);

    datos_OK.setLayoutParams(testLP);
    datos_OK.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_delete);
    datos_OK.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    linearLayout.addView(datos_OK);
```

let me know your feedback's..

Comment: Thx a lot, just for my code I have edittext's and textview's and I need to create the layout's by xml.